# jQuery .attr() does not set custom attribute and value

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm simply setting a custom attribute in the document.ready function in the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.para, pre.screen, div.figure, pre.programlisting").attr("data-test-ID", "hello");
});
```

When I reload the HTML and look at the source, there is no trace of such attribute anywhere. Any ideas? I'm really stuck on this and can't figure it out.

Comment: Look in the DOM (with `inspect element` in your browser's context menu) the HTML source of the page isn't, and *can't*, be touched by JavaScript.

Comment: It would never show up. Look in the console of chrome instead. The set .data("testid") instead

Comment: @DavidThomas, ah, you're of course right... Silly me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This in fact works, you have to look at the DOM (Document Object Model) as any changes done by javascript do not directly edit the page source. the source will always be exactly what the server sent.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.para, pre.screen, div.figure, pre.programlisting").attr("data-test-ID", "hello");
    $("#result").text("para contains :" + $("div.para").attr("data-test-ID"));//view value
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eventor29/aUvVJ/1/)

Using Chrome or Firefox, Right Click on the element and click Inspect Element to view the values set by the DOM to the element

You code is correct and the value is infact set :)

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer. Hopefully this will serve future questioners to avoid silly mistakes :)

Comment: Your welcome! Silly mistakes happen to all, sometimes all we need is a helping hand :)